# Classification of monoidal closed structures

Tags: category-theory, big-list, monoidal-categories, big-picture

The motivations for this question are somewhat *vague* probably. I am trying to have a better *understanding of monoidal closed structures*. In order to do so I would like to collect unusual examples and trivial patterns.

> **Q1**.  Could you help me to generate a list of **examples in which the monoidal closed structure is very different from the one related to Set?** It happens very often that when $\mathsf{K}$ is cartesian closed and concrete $\mathsf{U}: \mathsf{K} \to \mathsf{Set}$, $\mathsf{U}(a^b)$ is a proper subobject of $\mathsf{U}(a)^{\mathsf{U}(b)}$. This is the kind of example that I want to *avoid*.
>
> **Q2**. Assume that $\mathsf{K}$ is complete and cocomplete. Is it true that  **$\mathsf{K}$ always admits a monoidal closed structure?** Can you describe such a structure? If not, could you provide a counterexample?

---

This question is closely related or maybe even a duplicate of [this other one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338599/are-there-categories-whose-internal-hom-is-somewhat-exotic).

**Examples** of interesting monoidal closed structures.

1. Heyting algebras are precisely **cartesian closed** bounded lattices. In that case the internal exponentiation $a^b$ is the implication $b \Rightarrow a$.
2. ... I will add some if I think about them.

Comment: For your Q2, consider a complete lattice which is not a Heyting algebra.

Comment: @Berci, I am sorry but I do not see how this is an answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Berci Every complete distributive lattice admits a Heyting algebra structure (here I have in mind an infinite distributive law), so I suppose your suggestion amounts to considering a complete lattice which is not distributive. e.g. any finite non-distributive lattice, like $M_3$ or $N_5$.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1.** Here's a large class of examples. In the linked MO question I described the cartesian closed structure on a presheaf category $[C^{op}, \text{Set}]$. This construction can be generalized to get non-cartesian structures as follows. If $V$ is a closed, symmetric monoidal, complete and cocomplete category (typical choices are $V = \text{Set}$ or $V = \text{Vect}$) and $C$ is a small monoidal $V$-enriched category, then the enriched presheaf category $[C^{op}, V]$ has a closed monoidal structure where the monoidal structure is given by [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution#ClosedMonoidalStructure) and the closed structure is given by a certain end.

This is an absurdly general construction even in the case $V = \text{Set}$. If you want to work out an example, try taking $V = \text{Set}$ and $C$ to be the category of finite sets and bijections with monoidal structure given by disjoint union; then $[C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ is the category of [combinatorial species](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/species) with Day convolution giving the Cauchy product of species.

For another class of examples see [quantales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantale).

**Q2.** No. We will show that if $D$ is a noncommutative division ring, then the category $\text{Mod}(D)$ of right $D$-modules admits no closed monoidal structures.

For starters, observe that in any monoidal category, the endomorphism monoid of the unit object is commutative by the Eckmann-Hilton argument. But the endomorphism monoids of right $D$-modules are (possibly infinite-dimensional) matrix rings over $D$, and hence are noncommutative except in the case of the zero module. Thus the zero module is the only possible unit object of any monoidal structure on $\text{Mod}(D)$. But:

> **Lemma:** In a closed monoidal category $C$, the unit object $I$ cannot also be the initial object unless $C$ is contractible (equivalent to a category with one object and one morphism).

*Proof.* In a closed monoidal category, $(-) \otimes X$ has a right adjoint and hence preserves colimits, in particular the initial object. So if $I$ is the initial object and also the unit object, then we have both $I \otimes X \cong I$ and $I \otimes X \cong X$. Hence in this case every object is initial. $\Box$

So the zero module cannot be the unit object in a closed monoidal structure on $\text{Mod}(D)$, and hence there is no such structure.